# Replace multiple consecutive characters with their last occurrence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

When `3*+8` is entered the answer should be `11` and when `9+*/3` is entered the answer should be `3`.

The code:

```
operation=()=>{
   this.setState({ result:(eval(this.state.result.replace(/[-+\/*]/gm, "$1"))||"")+""})}
```

Comment: Try `.replace(/([-+\/*])+/g, "$1")`

Comment: When i try with that the answer of 3*+8=24but i want the answer be 11

Comment: `eval("3*+8".replace(/([-+\/*])+/g, "$1"))` => `11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a streak of one or more `+`, `-`, `/` or `*` math operators and replace them with their last occurrence:

```
.replace(/([-+\/*])+/g, "$1")
```

Here, `([-+\/*])+` is a *repeated capturing group* that matches and captures into Group 1 any of the four chars, and only keeps the last char captured during the last iteration in the group memory buffer. The `$1` backreference replaces the whole match with that char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M49iOx/1).

```js
const strs = ["3*+8", "9+*/3"];
const rx = /([-+\/*])+/g;
for (const s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', eval(s.replace(rx, "$1")));
}
```

Comment: This is a nice usage of a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) that is often mistakenly used to fetch multiple matches. It seems `/` can be left unescaped in this regex.

Comment: Yes, in most cases, `/` can be left unescaped inside a character class. It did not work in IE and old browser versions.